# how to post a multi-selected items and received correctly by request object in django?

Tags: python, django, post, request

I have form of multi select choicefield in django 1.5.5(python 2.7):

```
select_fields=forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=select_choices, required=True, widget = forms.SelectMultiple)
```

when I post, I post:

```
sector=65&select_fields=141&select_fields=142&select_fields=143
```

But on django service side when I want to received:

```
o=request.REQUEST['select_fields']
print o
```

I only received the last one
I mean I only get the 143 value for above example, but I want to get ['141', '142', '143']
how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`QueryDict.getlist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) method.

```
request.GET.getlist('select_fields')
```

In my example I have used `request.GET` because it makes it clearer that you are fetching GET parameters. Using `request.REQUEST.getlist('select_fields')` would work as well, but note that `request.REQUEST` is deprecated in Django 1.7.